# Does an Orc fighter have any use for Orc Weapon Expertise?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, proficiency

Gragnar the Mightily Tusked is a fighter. At first level, he took [Orc Weapon Familiarity](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=86). This makes advanced orc weapons martial orc weapons for Gragnar.

I assume this means that, as his proficiency increases to expert, etc., in martial weapons, he also gains that proficiency with an Orc necksplitter.

But [Orc Weapon Expertise](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=91) states

> Whenever you gain a class feature that grants you expert or greater proficiency in a given weapon or weapons, you also gain that proficiency in the falchion, the greataxe, and all orc weapons in which you are trained.

Does Gragnar have any use for this, if the Orc necksplitter is treated as a martial weapon and he therefore gets the proficiency increases?

If not, is this feat more directed at characters who don't necessarily get increased proficiency with all martial weapons? For example, an Orc Warpriest, who only gains expert proficiency with their deity's favoured weapon?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Fighters in particular, Orc weapon expertise *does* have an effect. Notably, Fighters get to choose one weapon group that gets higher proficiency over their other weapons - such as swords or axes (they get Master in these weapons at 5 where their other weapons stay at Expert, and at level 13 they bump to Legendary in these weapons while they only bump their normal weapons to Master).

Thus, if Gragnar the Mightily Tusked takes Orc Weapon Expertise at 13, he could have chosen anything as his Fighter weapon group (say, Hammers). He'd then get Legendary in Hammers at that level, *as well as* with Falchions, Greataxes, and all weapons with the orc trait (currently knuckle daggers and necksplitters).

Note that Fighters are currently the only martial class with this same concept of choosing one weapon group; barbarians, swashbucklers, investigators, and a few others get all their weapons equally (Warpriest and Rogues are the notable exceptions).

Comment: Having looked more closely at the fighter features at the levels you mention, I can see you're right. Thanks for that insight.